# Memory efficiency of C++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, size

Somewhere in my brainstem a voice whispers:

> In C++, an array does not need more memory than the number of elements
>   need.

```
std::string str = "aabbcc"; 
std::array<std::string, 3> str_array = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
```

Accordingly, both should have the same size, because (unlike in Java), there is no separate *size* field or similar. But I haven't found a reference.

Is this true? Under which circumstances is it not?

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` is not `6`.

Comment: Nor `2`.........................

Comment: And neither is `sizeof std::string("aabbcc");`

Comment: 1 `std::string` can't be the same size as 3 `std::string`s

Comment: Sorry for the bad example with size of 6 - I removed it.

Comment: I'm no biology expert, but I find it highly unlikely anyone's brainstem is capable of this level of abstract thought -- that's the part of our brains responsible for keeping our hearts, lungs, and other basic body functionality working.

Comment: The example is not the problem, your understanding of how `std::string` works is flawed. The size of that object is not proportional to the length of the string it points to.

Comment: Don't confuse std::string and std::array with the old C-style types that C++ inherited.  `char s1[] = "aabbcc"; char *s2 = "aabbcc";` In these, s1 is 7 bytes (6 characters plus NUL terminator) while s2 is the size of a pointer.  But std::string and std::array are smarter classes (e.g. std::string does not use NUL for terminator but keeps a separate length), so they have different implementations than the old types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++, an array does not need more memory than the number of elements need.

This is true.  A raw array has a size equal to the size of it's element type times the number of elements.  So,

```
int array[10];
```

has a size of `sizeof(int) * std::size(array)`.  `std::array` is the same but it is allowed to have padding so

```
std::array<int, 10> array;
```

has the size of `sizeof(int) * std::size(array) + P` where `P` is some integer amount of padding.

Your example though isn't quite the same thing.
A `std::string` is a container.  It has it's own size that is separate of what it contains.  So `sizeof(std::string)` will always be the same thing regardless of how many characters are in the string.  So ignoring short string optimization

```
std::string str = "aabbcc";
```

Takes of `sizeof(std::string)` plus however much the string allocated for the underlying c-string.  That is not the same value as

```
std::array<std::string, 3> str_array = {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
```

Since you now have `3 * sizeof(std::string)` plus whatever each string allocated.

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` may differ between SSO version and non-SSO.

Comment: Last time I checked (and it was years ago) `std::array` was allowed to have some padding at the end.

Comment: @juanchopanza and it is still allowed.

Comment: @juanchopanza It is required to be an aggregate so I'm not sure if that still allows it or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver The aggregate requirement doesn't affect whether it can have padding or not.

Comment: @juanchopanza Updated to include there could be some padding.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes I did.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 4):

Storing strings in any language is more complicated than you think. A C++ `std::string` must provide you contiguous storage for the contents. Apart from that, `std::string` can hold more things, like pointer/iterator to the last character, number of characters in it, etc. `std::string::size` is required to be O(1), so it must store more information than just a buffer. Also, most standard library implementations provide SSO (small string optimization). When SSO is enabled, `std::string` allocates a small buffer, to avoid unneccessary dynamic allocations. You can also reserve more memory than you need. Lets say, you need to collect 800-1000 characters in loop. You can do it like this:

```
std::string str;
for(...)
    str += some_character;
```

But this will cause unneccessary memory allocations and deallocations. If you can estimate number of characters you want to store, you should [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) memory.

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(1000);
for(...)
    str.push_back(some_character);
```

Then, you can always [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit), to save memory:

```
str.shrink_to_fit();
```

There are also other things you must be aware of:

- `reserve` increases capacity, but `size` stays the same. It means, that `std::string` must also store (or be able to calculate) for how many more characters buffer capacity allows.
- string literals are null terminated
- `std::basic_string::c_str` must return null terminated array of characters, so it is possible that `std::string` also contains null terminator (unluckily I am not sure how it is done)
- there are more encodings and characters sets - ASCII is just one of them. UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoded strings may need to use few stored elements to add up to one code point, but this is more complicated.

Comment: Some?  I guess there might exist a std library that does not do SSO currently.  Some obscure embedded one?

Comment: Well, I don't know. I did not want to mislead. You are right, let me change it.

Answer (score 1):

> Accordingly, both should have the same size (e.g. 6 bytes),

Not a correct deduction.

The memory used by a `std::string`, if you want to call its size, consists of at least a pointer and the memory allocated to hold the data.

The memory allocated to hold the data can also include the space required to hold the terminating null character.

Given

```
std::string s = "aabbcc";
std::string a = "aa";
std::string b = "bb";
std::string c = "cc";

mem(s) != mem(a) + mem(b) + mem(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

Virtually every string can hold following info:

- The size of the string i.e. num of chars it contains.
- The capacity of memory holding the string's chars.
- The value of the string.

Additionally it may also hold:

- A copy of it's allocator and reference count for the value.

Answer (score -2):

They don’t have the same size. Strings are saved null-terminated, giving you an extra byte for each string.

Comment: Null terminators isn't the half of it. You're forgetting the overhead of `std::string` itself.